# translate(x, y) why extra gap is created between each element

Tags: javascript, css

I am just checking css transforms using below code

```
var style="-webkit-transform: translate(0px, {{ht}}px);-ms-transform: translate(0px, {{ht}}px);transform: translate(0px, {{ht}}px)";

var str = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    str.push('<div class="ele" style="', style.replace(/\{\{ht\}\}/g, i * 25) ,'">', i, '</div>');
}

document.body.innerHTML = str.join('');
```

But when I check the result, `25px` extra gap is created between each item. [What is the reason and how to fix it properly](http://jsfiddle.net/3uxetm4p/1/)? (fiddle link)

Comment: You haven't said what you're trying to do... the CSS you've posted will move each subsequent `<div>` down 25px below the previous one, which is expected behaviour. What are you trying to do instead?

Comment: This is the reason why: `style.replace(/\{\{ht\}\}/g, i * 25)` moves the divs 25px away from each other. You can replace 25 with a smaller number like 10. Sorry for the terrible explanation. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/wa4ctpjy/

Comment: @Joe I am expecting each one to display one below another without gap. Can you help out?

Comment: Just remove the translation then. `<div>`s are block-level elements naturally which means that they'll appear below each other without any additional code

Comment: @Joe Is not y value in translate(x, y) equal to top value as in absolute positioning?

Comment: No because in absolute positioning the `<div>` is taken out of the normal flow of the document. Here, as they're just statically positioned (default) they're still in the flow, so your translate takes effect from the end of the previous `<div>`, not the start

Comment: @Joe Oh fish!  Thanks for educating me :)